# Pytest does not connect to the database when I run the test selectively

Tags: postgresql, unit-testing, python-3.6, pytest

guys, tell me please, what can be caused by such anomalous behavior pytest?

1. I run so `pytest` - all tests pass.
2. I run sample tests, either - `pytest tests/gate/test_loan.py :: Tests :: test_pass`.  Of course, it breaks, it can be seen from the stack that it breaks due to the fact that it can not be attached to the database. The question is how the second type of test run affects the connection from the database.

Comment: You have to create an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add it to your question.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not put the code, but it will not come to anything either. It is important for me to understand the direction in which to think. I ask exactly about the behavior, maybe someone had something like that.

Comment: Then do a bisect to determine the test whose removal breaks the test run and investigate what makes the test special, maybe it opens the db connection that is then used by other tests etc. Without the code and even the error stack trace, it is pretty much impossible to say anything helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I understood this behavior.
Problem was relatid with wrong import of db_session.
**main.app1.db.py**

```
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker())
```

**tests.conftest.py**

```
from app1.db import  db_session
```

right import
**tests.conftest.py**

```
from main.app1.db import  db_session
```